# How to call c# method in xslt 1.0

Tags: c#, xslt

Is there a way to call c# method by xslt(1.0) file? I have a converter method that called by some methods (and it calls some other methods), and now I want to use it in xslt. is there a way to call it by xslt? or I have to write it in xslt format?

Comment: A quick look at the methods of [`XslCompiledTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) does not indicate any means to extend the set of functions available in the transform (you can only handle how XML documents are loaded).

Comment: Microsoft only: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6datxzsd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for the Microsoft .NET `XslCompiledTransform` XSLT 1.0 processor, you can use extension objects passed in using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and/or you can use the `ms:script` extension element to write your C# (or VB.NET or JScript.NET) code inline in your XSLT code, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

In general the ability to call into .NET is something you find in XSLT processors implemented in .NET (like Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` (and the old `XslTransform`) as XSLT 1.0 processors) or XmlPrime or Saxon 9 .NET version as XSLT 2.0 processors.